# Upload User image

Tags: php, mysql, upload

Hi ive been trying to make an User IMAGE upload thingy. the image should be saved in a folder, and in the database only the link to the image. It

it gives me the else answer from if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))

heres my code:

```
<?php
require_once "common.php";
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION["user"];

// get userimage
$dbc = @new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
if ($dbc->connect_error) die("Database connection failed: $dbc->connect_error");
$dbc->set_charset("utf8");
$query = "SELECT userimage FROM members WHERE username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$userimagearray = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$userimage = $userimagearray["userimage"];
//
//upload userimg
$imagedir = "../images/userimages/";
$uploadfile = $imagedir . basename($username);
if(isset($_POST["sendfile"])){
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "Upload Worked.\n";
//Update Database Entry
$updateimage = "UPDATE members ".
    "SET userimage = '<<mysite>>/Uploaduserimage/images/userimages    /$username' ".
    "WHERE username = $username";
mysqli_query($dbc, $updateimage);


} else {
echo "Error!\n";
}
}
//

?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify the error, or should we guess?

Comment: There is a lot of library to to that properly. Try a Google search.

Comment: it gives me the else answer from if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))